# How to upload & display image in MVC Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to write simple MVC Razor app that will load image from file into view model and display it. I can't find simple solution for that.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: How do you want to store your image ? In a folder or in database ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to load it into a view model?  Just Link to it.

If using Razor 1

```
<img src="@Html.Content("~/Content/images/myimage.jpg")" />
```

If using Razor 2

```
<img src="~/images/myimage.jpg" />
```

If this is not what you want, then you need to be clearer about what exactly you are trying to do.